# Why does my Python-Requests script keep downloading the same page when using a list of URLs?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to download the contents of a site. I am the legal owner of the following site and I am trying to download the pictures from this site.
So far I have obtained the urls of the individual pages, in this text document urls.txt:

```
http://www.x10.com.cn/front/active-view-content?code=pRqKeo&active_role_id=p36Pao&content_id=p36Pao
http://www.x10.com.cn/front/active-view-content?code=pRqKeo&active_role_id=p36Pao&content_id=zZB9ez
http://www.x10.com.cn/front/active-view-content?code=pRqKeo&active_role_id=p36Pao&content_id=zAKnqp
http://www.x10.com.cn/front/active-view-content?code=pRqKeo&active_role_id=p36Pao&content_id=227420
http://www.x10.com.cn/front/active-view-content?code=pRqKeo&active_role_id=p36Pao&content_id=227378
--snip--
```

And I have tried to use secondary_page.py to try to download the images on each page:

```py
import requests
import bs4
import time

with open("urls.txt") as file_object:
    urls = file_object.readlines()
for url in urls:
    print(f"URL={url}")
    resp = requests.get(url)
    txt = resp.text
    sp = bs4.BeautifulSoup(txt)
    names = sp.select("div[class='field-value xingming']")
    imgs = sp.select("img[data-src]")
    for i in range(0, 2):
        img = imgs[i]
        link = img.get("data-src")
        res2 = requests.get(link)
        with open(f"caches/{names[0].text}_{i + 1}.jpg", "wb") as file_object:
            for chunk in res2.iter_content(100000):
                file_object.write(chunk)
            print(f"DOWNLOADING {names[0]}_{i + 1}.jpg")
    time.sleep(1)
```

but for some reason it won't work.

The problem is that it keeps downloading the same page (specifically the first page) over and over although I had specified for it not to do so.
I have included my debug method in the code.
I have attempted to find out if the urls were right. They were. (The print statement. Every time it outputted a different url. )
I have then attempted to use `time.sleep(1)` to try to ensure the website does not block me, but to no avail.

Comment: You have numerous issues. Firstly, the url.strip() code won't do anything to your URLs. Remember, Python strings are immutable. Secondly, if you want to use tier_content you need to specify stream=True to request.get()

Comment: @DarkKnight I've modified the code accordingly, but the problem persists. However, what is tier_content? I was not trying to use it and I can't think of where I used it unconsciously.

Comment: tier_content was a typo. Damned autocorrect. Should be iter_content. I've look at these pages. Each page has multiple images. You need to figure out which ones are of interest. Just dump the HTML and you'll see

Comment: @DarkKnight Specifically I want the images inside `<div class="content-photos content-item">`. It should have three sub-divs, one with class="field-name" and two with class="field-value".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is slightly different inasmuch as the actual image file names are used as the target output.

Also uses multithreading for enhanced performance

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as TPE
import os

TARGET_DIRECTORY = '/Volumes/G-Drive/jpgs'
URL_LIST = '/Volumes/G-Drive/urls.txt'
image_set = set()

def process(url):
    print('Processing', url)
    filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    with open(os.path.join(TARGET_DIRECTORY, filename), 'wb') as jpg:
        with requests.get(url, stream=True) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            for chunk in response.iter_content(16*1024):
                jpg.write(chunk)

with TPE() as tpe:
    with open(URL_LIST) as file:
        for url in map(str.strip, file):
            with requests.get(url) as response:
                response.raise_for_status()
                soup = BS(response.text, 'lxml')
                for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='content-photos content-item'):
                    for img in div.select('img[data-src]'):
                        image = img.get('data-src')
                        if not image in image_set:
                            image_set.add(image)
                            tpe.submit(process, image)
```